# Symfony2: How to get container parameters from parameters.yml in a twig filter/extension?

Tags: php, symfony

I have file `parameters.yml` :

```
parameters:
    ............
    image_news_url: http://image.dev/news/
```

Now in my bundle I create a new twig extension :

```
// src/DesktopBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php

namespace App\DesktopBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('get_image', array($this, 'getImage')),
    );
}

public function getImage($domen, $image_id)
{
    $o_container = new ContainerBuilder();

    switch($domen){
        case 'news':
            return sprintf('%s%s',$o_container->getParameter('image_news_url'),$image_id.'.slide.jpg');
            break;
    }
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'app_extension';
}
```

}
And I have an error : `You have requested a non-existent parameter "image_news_url`. Can you help me please ? I don't understand why I don't have access to parameters.yml. Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that you try to build a container yourself.

```
$o_container = new ContainerBuilder();
```

This is wrong.

You just need to  inject the container into your extension if you want access to it.

**Config**

```
services:

    # [..]    

    your.twig_extension:
        class: Your\Namespace\YourExtension
        public: false
        arguments: [ "@service_container" ]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**Class**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

namespace Your\Namespace;

class YourExtension 
{
    /** @var ContainerInterface */
    protected $container;

    /** @param ContainerInterface $container */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /** @return string */
    function getImage()
    {
        // some logic here

        return $this->container->getParameter('image_news_url');
    }
```

---

I assume you want to apply some additonal logic to select parameters in your extension. Otherwise you could simply:

- inject only the parameter itself `%image_news_url%`
- use the `twig.globals` config directive

There's an example in the documentation chapter [Using Service Container Parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html#using-service-container-parameters).

**app/config/parameters.yml**

```
image_news_url: "http://some-url.tld"
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
twig:
    globals:
       image_news_url: %image_news_url%
```

**Template**

```
{{ image_news_url }}
```

Comment: +1; for completeness, the best pratice would be avoiding the code becoming dependent on the Container, so if you inject only the parameter with `arguments: ['%image_news_url%']` is a better choice.

Comment: totally agree that it'd be best practice to inject the parameter itself. :)

I've seen the `switch` statement though and so i thought he wants to select parameters based on some conditions. That's why i used the container itself in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$o_container = new ContainerBuilder();`

Simply declaring a new instance of a `ContainerBuilder` will not give you access to another (already existing) instance. You need to *inject* the instance that already exists. And - you don't actually want that, you only want *one* parameter, so you can simply inject that.

In your service definition where you created the Twig extension, you need to inject this parameter. so, you should have something that looks like this in your `services.xml` file...

```
    <service id="twig.extension.desktop_bundle" class="App\DesktopBundle\Twig\AppExtension" public="false">
        <argument>%image_news_url%</argument>
        <tag name="twig.extension" />
    </service>
```

Then, in your Extension class, you need to use a constructor:

```
namespace App\DesktopBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $url;
    public function __construct($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now you can use `$this->url` wherever you need the value.

read up on [Dependency Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html) for more information.

Comment: I assume he wanted to apply additional logic in the extension to select which parameter to fetch. otherwise the extension would be overkill -> see my answer regarding the use of `twig.globals` to add variables that hold container parameters in twig templates.

Comment: This should be the correct solution as @Harea Costicla is using `image_news_url` in `AppExtension` service..